# How to ask setup.py to install custom local package?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am new to python install logic. I would like to ask a main `setup.py` to install local packages first. Let's say I have this architecture:

```
main_package /
   sub_package_1 / 
      __init__.py
   sub_package_2 /
      __init__.py
   sub_package_3 /
      __init__.py
      apis_for_3 /
         api_0 / 
            setup.py
   setup.py
```

Is it possible to link `main_package/sub_package_3/apis_for_3/api_0` as install requirements in `main_package/setup.py` ?

Comment: your subpackages are actually submodules. And why would you need a `setup.py` your submodule?

Comment: the api contain cython that needs to compile either c and cuda files from somewhere else

Comment: When you see the need for more than one setup.py it's usually time to split up your project.

Comment: why can't the main `setup.py` do the cython compiling?

Comment: Let's split then !